# Is there any differences in two sentences?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adverbs

Here are two sentences below.

1. I would have taken a lot for her to say that.
2. I would have taken her a lot to say that.
   The position of 'a lot' makes the difference?

Comment: Do you mean "It would have taken...."?

Comment: I've answered on the assumption that should be ***It***, not ***I*** (the latter simply makes no sense at all).

Answer (score 1):

> 1: *It would have taken a lot for her to say that.*
> 2: *It would have taken her a lot to say that.*

---

The first version is non-specific about ***who*** might need to make significant changes in order for something to occur. Perhaps the intended meaning is ***WE would have to make a lot of effort** to get her to say that*.

The second version makes it clear that ***SHE** is the one who would have to suffer / make the effort* (note that the "suffering" interpretation probably wouldn't make sense unless it was specifically ***her*** - not "us", society at large, or whatever).

---

If you're not interested in that *potential* distinction, they're equivalent and interchangeable.